# How to reduce processing time for imread and imwrite

Tags: matlab, image-processing, parallel-processing, imread

I am working on a 3d reconstruction using parallel computing in Matlab. I profiled my code and found that imread and imwrite took most of the processing time. My goal is to significantly reduce the processing time as my simulations involve large data sets and iterations.
My code:

```
projection_length = 4100;
parfor q = 1:projection_length
    tmpData = zeros(1600, 500);
    for i = 1:500
        fname= sprintf('pre%03d.tif', i);
        tmpData(:, i) = imread(fname, 'PixelRegion', {[1 1600], [q q]});

        disp(['Analyzing projection ' num2str(q)  ' of ' num2str(projection_length) ', Angle ' num2str(i) '...']);
    end
    idata=255-tmpData;
    H = iradon(idata, 0.72, 'Hann', 0.8, 1600 );
    postfname= sprintf('post%06d.tif', q);
    imwrite(H, postfname);
end
```

Comment: Please properly indent your code!

Comment: are you reading data from a network or local file system?

Comment: I am reading data from a local file system

Comment: Yes @A.Donda, it did reduce the processing time to some extent. I profiled my code and found out that 50% of the processing time is used in imwrite-writing the images. Is there any suggestion to reduce time for writing images too?

Comment: Well, if you happen to repeatedly write the same images file, too, then the same advice applies. Otherwise, probably not. For a better answer you should post the relevant code.

Comment: The images that I am writing are not same. They are cross-sectional images of each of the 4100 slices. after writing the images I stack them one after the other in Imagej software. This is the relevant code itself. I have accepted your answer but I want to reduce the time even more as 50% of the processing time is used to write those images

Comment: @A.Donda each image that I am writing is different from one another.

Comment: In that case I doubt the writing time can be reduced. What you have there are basically file access times, not much to do about that. What might help is using compression, or maybe using a file format that can accomodate all the slices at once.

Comment: Instead of imwrite can other lower level functions be used such as wtifc as imwrite performs a lot of checks does other stuff too which probably results in more processing time? @A.Donda

Comment: Lower level functions might help, but I wouldn't expect that much. Another  idea: Save the files to a RAM disk (on Linux: tmpfs). You still have to copy to a real disk later, but at least while processing it will be faster.

Comment: `imwrite` supports LZW compression for TIFFs, see whether that helps.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you read the same 500 images over and over again, only to access different pixel regions. Better to read the images once, and then access the pixel regions using standard array slicing.

I can't really test the code because I don't have your image files and functions, but it should look something like this:

```
% preload images
images = {};
for i = 1:500
    fname= sprintf('pre%03d.tif', i);
    images{i} = imread(fname);
end
% analyze images
projection_length = 4100;
parfor q = 1:projection_length
    tmpData = zeros(1600, 500);
    for i = 1:500
        tmpData(:, i) = images{i}(1 : 1600, q, :);
        disp(['Analyzing projection ' num2str(q)  ' of ' num2str(projection_length) ', Angle ' num2str(i) '...']);
    end
    idata=255-tmpData;
    H = iradon(idata, 0.72, 'Hann', 0.8, 1600 );
    postfname= sprintf('post%06d.tif', q);
    imwrite(H, postfname);
end
```

Comment: Better yet - if all images are same sizes (as I would expect 'frames' to be), use a 3D array instead of a cell array.

Comment: @A.Donda I just found that the above code runs serially because of some serailisation error, this was shown by Matlab when I run the code. I think it is because Matlab keeps showing that the variable "images" is indexed and not sliced which might result in a communication overhead. The code did run parallely for smaller data sets. Do you have any suggestions? Can the variable be sliced/sliced in a different way?

Comment: @TusharAnchan, this comment appears because all of the images are used in each part of the parfor loop. This could be repaired by also generating `idata` outside of parfor, and storing the results in a cell array that is indexed by `q`; access to this variable would be sliced. I wouldn't expect too much speed-up by the parallelization though, since most of the time is probably spent in writing the images, which cannot be done in parallel anyway.